# CUDA streams not running in parallel

Tags: c++, cuda, nvvp

Given this code:

```
void foo(cv::gpu::GpuMat const &src, cv::gpu::GpuMat *dst[], cv::Size const dst_size[], size_t numImages)
{
    cudaStream_t streams[numImages];
    for (size_t image = 0; image < numImages; ++image)
    {
        cudaStreamCreateWithFlags(&streams[image], cudaStreamNonBlocking);
        dim3 Threads(32, 16);
        dim3 Blocks((dst_size[image].width + Threads.x - 1)/Threads.x,
                    (dst_size[image].height + Threads.y - 1)/Threads.y);
        myKernel<<<Blocks, Threads, 0, streams[image]>>>(src, dst[image], dst_size[image]);
    }
    for (size_t image = 0; image < numImages; ++image)
    {
        cudaStreamSynchronize(streams[image]);
        cudaStreamDestroy(streams[image]);
    }
}
```

Looking at the output of `nvvp`, I see almost perfectly serial execution, even though the first stream is a lengthy process that the others should be able to overlap with.

Note that my kernel uses 30 registers, and all report an "Achieved Occupancy" of around 0.87. For the smallest image, Grid Size is [10,15,1] and Block Size [32, 16,1].

Comment: You are launching 150 blocks per kernel. Your GPU would have to have enough free resource in order for blocks from another another stream to be schedule. Does it? What is the question here?

Comment: I have a GTX 980M, which has 2048 threads per multiprocessor and 1024 threads per block. Am I creating so many threads or blocks that only one kernel can run at a time - is that what the 87% occupancy is telling me?

Comment: By my reckoning uour GPU can have a maximum of 4 blocks running on each SMM, and you have something like 12 SMM in your GPU. So your limit of concurrent blocks would be 48. If your kernel launch is 150 blocks, not all the blocks in a single kernel launch could from concurrently. The scope for multiple kernel launches to run concurrently is rather limited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conditions describing the limits for concurrent kernel execution are given in the CUDA programming guide ([link](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#concurrent-kernel-execution)), but the gist of it is that your GPU can potentially run multiple kernels from different streams only if your GPU has sufficient resources to do so.

In your usage case, you have said that you are running multiple launches of a kernel with 150 blocks of 512 threads each. Your GPU has 12 SMM (I think), and you could have *up to* 4 blocks per SMM running concurrently (4 * 512 = 2048 threads, which is the SMM limit). So your GPU can only run a maximum of 4 * 12 = 48 blocks concurrently. When multiple launches of 150 blocks sitting in the command pipeline, it would seem that there is little (perhaps even no) opportunity for concurrent kernel execution.

You *might* be able to encourage kernel execution overlap if you increase the scheduling granularity of you kernel by reducing the block size. Smaller blocks are more likely to find available resources and scheduling slots than larger blocks. Similarly, reducing the total block count per kernel launch (probably by increasing the parallel work per thread) *might* also help increase the potential for overlap or concurrent execution of multiple kernels.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation; my actual code takes just 400 μs to run on even the biggest image and I do see a slight overlap (around 2 or 3 μs) using `nvvp` which might be explained by some SMMs finishing slightly quicker than others. I'm working on another more complex kernel now and will later be porting to a more beefy card, so this backgrounder will help if I have performance issues there.

Comment: @keny-n: if this answer works for you, could you accept it? It makes them more visible in search, amongst other things